# What does this shell script line of code mean

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I need some help understanding following shell script line,

```
apphome =     "`cd \`dirname $0\` && pwd && cd - >/dev/null`"
```

All I understand is, this is creating a variable called apphome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** a valid shell code.

The shell don't allow spaces around `=`

For the rest, while this seems broken, it try to `cd` to the dir of the script itself, display the current dir & finally `cd` back to the latest `cd` place redirecting his standard output `STDOUT` to the `/dev/null` trash-bin (that's makes not any sense, `cd` display only on standard error `STDERR` when it fails, never on `STDOUT`)

If you want to do this in a proper a simple way :

```
apphome="$(dirname $0)"
```

That's all you need.

**NOTE**

The backquote

`

is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The

```
foo=$(command)
```

syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Isn't cd'ing into the directory -- to see if it is there -- possible part of some hackish try/catch logic? What happens to the value of apphome if the cd fails vs succeeds?

Comment: I don't know any case where `cd` can fails to `cd` to an existing place : the script exists in this path.

Comment: See my new **NOTE** in my post.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to assign a command to the "apphome" variable. This command can be executed later.
dirname returns a directory portion of a file name. $0 is the name of the script this line contains (if I am not mistaken).
Now, executing `dirname <name>` will return a directory, and cd will use the value.
So, what it would do is execute three command in the row assuming that each one of them succeeds. The commands are:

```
cd `dirname [name of the script]`
pwd
cd -
```

First command will change directory to the directory containing your script; second will print current directory; third will take yo back to the original directory. Output of the third command will not be printed out.
In summary, it will print out a name of a directory containing the script that contains the line in question.
At least, this is how I understand it.

Comment: As sputnick points out, spaces around "=" are not allowed. I assumed formatting issues in the post. Also, sputnick is quite correct about a much easier way of achieving what this line does.

Comment: In bash, if I run d="\`date\`" and check the date, and then echo $d, I find that the date stored in d was from before the check date, and so the date command was executed immediately and was not held for later execution.